# How to list file and folder names in powershell?

Tags: powershell, command-line, file-listing

I want to write all files and folders' names into a `.gitignore` file like the below:

```
Folder1
Folder2
File1.bar
File2.foo
```

and so on.

The writing part can be achieved with the `Out-File` command, but I'm stuck in printing those names like the format above.

I'm aware of the command `Get-ChildItem` but it prints out a bunch of metadata like dates and icons too which are useless for the matter. btw, I'm looking for a single-line **command**, not a script.

Comment: the fileinfo object that you get from that cmdlet has a `.Name` property that holds _just the name_ of the file.  also, the `-Name` parameter of that cmdlet will return JUST the name of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just print the `Name` property of the files

```
$ (ls).Name >.gitignore
$ (Get-ChildItem).Name | Out-File .gitignore
```

Comment: Thanks. Both commands will do the job. Please separate them and add `$` at the beginning of them so they can be more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm aware of the command `Get-ChildItem` but it prints out a bunch of metadata like dates and icons [...]

That's because PowerShell cmdlets output complex objects rather than raw strings. The metadata you're seeing for a file is all attached to a [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) object that describes the underlying file system entry.

To get only the names, simply reference the `Name` property of each. For this, you can use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
# Enumerate all the files and folders
$fileSystemItems = Get-ChildItem some\root\path -Recurse |Where-Object Name -ne .gitignore
# Grab only their names
$fileSystemNames = $fileSystemItems |ForEach-Object Name

# Write to .gitignore (beware git usually expects ascii or utf8-encoded configs)
$fileSystemNames |Out-File -LiteralPath .gitignore -Encoding ascii
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this do?

```
(get-childitem -Path .\ | select name).name | Out-File .gitignore
```

Comment: `select name` then `().name` is completely redundant